# Can Windows 2016 Standard support Rancher?

Tags: windows-server-2016, rancher

With the release of Rancher upon 1.3.0 version, Windows 2016 Datacenter with Container can provide the experimental support of Rancher. May I know whether there is any way that we can work with Rancher on Windows 2016 Standard version?

Answer (score 0):

`Docker for Windows` and `Docker for Windows Server` are very different things with similar names.

`Docker for Windows` creates a Linux Hyper-V VM on your PC and runs normal Docker and Docker containers.  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

`Docker for Windows Server` runs Windows containers on a port of the Docker engine to Windows.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

The Rancher support is for Windows containers on `Docker for Windows Server`.  Also I believe even `Docker for Windows` requires Windows 10 Pro or similar, not Standard.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vincent. Then, may I check with you about another question? I know that 'Windows 2016 Datacenter with Container' is a specific product. However, I may wonder whether it can be replaced or the same as Windows 2016 Datacenter in which I setup Docker?